# Build a load more data button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I’m currently building a blog and I’m trying to implement a load more button but I’m kinda stuck. Here is what I got :
I have a list of posts from a REST API that I call in in my Vuex Store:

```
actions: {
   LOAD_ARTICLE_LIST: function ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('someurl/articles').then((response) => {
      commit('SET_ARTICLE_LIST', { list: response.data.data })
       }, (err) => {
       console.log(err)
       })
   }
}
mutations: {
  SET_ARTICLE_LIST: (state, {list}) => {
    state.articles = list
   }
}
```

The simplified article component :

```
<div v-for="article in articles">
  <div> {{ article.title }}</div>
  <div> {{ article.description }}</div>
  <div> {{ article.date }}</div>
</div>
<div v-if="articles.length > 4" @click="loadMore">
  <div>More articles</div>
 </div>

 computed: {
   articles() {
      function compare(a, b) {   //sort articles by date
        if (a.date > b.date)
          return -1;
        if (a.date < b.date)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }

    let articleList = this.$store.state.articles.sort(compare);
    articleList.splice(0,5);
    return articleList
  }
 }

 mounted: function () {
   this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_ARTICLE_LIST')
 }
```

I know that I have to use the method calling loadMore(), and I think I have to push new articles in it but no idea how to do it. If someone could give me a hand, it would be so cool!

Thank you for reading

Note: if I push any articles with this method, will they be sorted by date with all the list or only with the new articles that I pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code snipnet and based on what i think you are trying to do. Try this:

```
    actions: {
      LOAD_ARTICLE_LIST: function ({ commit }) {
        axios.get('someurl/articles').then((response) => {
        commit('SET_ARTICLE_LIST', { list: response.data.data })
       }, (err) => {
       console.log(err)
       })
   }
}
mutations: {
  SET_ARTICLE_LIST: (state, {list}) => {
    function compare(a, b) {   //sort articles by date
      if (a.date > b.date)
        return -1;
      if (a.date < b.date)
        return 1;
      return 0;
     }
    state.articles = list.sort(compare);
   }
}
```

If sorting the data is really important, i'll suggest doing that once the data is recieved from the rest endpoint, just like i have done above.

Your article component should look like this:

```
<div v-for="article in articles">
  <div> {{ article.title }}</div>
  <div> {{ article.description }}</div>
  <div> {{ article.date }}</div>
</div>
<div v-if="articles.length > 5" @click="loadMore">
  <div>More articles</div>
 </div>

 computed: {
   articles() {
    let articleList = this.$store.state.articles;
    return articleList.splice(0, this.totalSize);
  }
 },

 data() {
    return {
      loadMoreSize: 5,
      totalSize: 0
    };
 },

 methods: {

   loadMore() {
     this.totalSize = this.loadMoreSize + this.articles.length;
   }

 },

 mounted: function () {
   this.loadMore();
   this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_ARTICLE_LIST')
 }
```

I have not tried this tho, but i hope it helps :)

Comment: It seems that it's working, it's amazing! Thank you so much :D